# Disable on esc key press for aui dialogue

Tags: user-interface, alloy-ui

In Alloy UI version is 2.0. is there any way to prevent closing dialog when esc key is pressed ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to listen for the ESC press and prevent the dialog from hiding:

```
Y.one('body').on('key', function(event) {
    modal.once('visibleChange', function(event) {
        if (event.prevVal === true) {
            event.newVal = true;
        }
    });
}, 'esc');
```

The above code attaches a one time visibleChange listener to the modal that ensures it will remain visible after ESC is pressed. Otherwise, the dialog can be hidden normally.

This may create a race condition though if the user presses ESC and immediately presses the *X* button. I'm not sure if the dialog would close in that case, but it seems pretty low risk.

Runnable Example:

```js
YUI().use('aui-modal', function(Y) {

  var modal = new Y.Modal({
    bodyContent: 'Modal body',
    centered: true,
    headerContent: '<h3>Modal header</h3>',
    modal: true,
    render: '#modal',
    width: 450
  }).render();

  Y.one('body').on('key', function(event) {
    modal.once('visibleChange', function(event) {
      if (event.prevVal === true) {
        event.newVal = true;
      }
    });
  }, 'esc');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/701826667a70997013605edcd37e92a6/raw/469fe1ae297e72a5a80eb9015003b7b04eac735e/alloy-ui-3.0.1_aui_aui-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/90be22de7f48c729b443af14796d91d3/raw/a9f35ceedfac7fc0559b121bed105eaf80f10bf2/aui-css_css_bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<div class="yui3-skin-sam">
  <div id="modal"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using AUI Dialog not modal

Comment: The principle is the same, have you tried the above code with `aui-dialog`?